# How to create selector to select an item by id from ngrx store

Tags: typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I read ngrx store's [documentation](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md) about selectors and need to figure out how to create a selector in order to select one item by item id. I already can do this as part of store subscription when I get all of the items from `selectAllItems` selector, but I need to figure out how to select specific item out of a list of items in the store. My main reason is that `createSelector` offers performance gains that I like to benefit from.

Here is my code:

```
import { AppState, Item } from '../../shared/models/index';
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

export const selectItems = (state: AppState) => state.eventsState;

export const selectAllItems = createSelector(selectItems, (allItems: { items: Item[] }) => {
  if (allItems && allItems.items) {
   return allItems.items.filter((item: Item) => (!item.active && !item.closed));
  } else {
    return allItems.items;
  }
});
```

Then in my controller i filter by id to get needed item:

```
this.store.select(selectors.selectAllItems)
  .filter(data => data !== null)
  .subscribe(allItems => {
    this.item = allItems.filter(item => {
      return item.id === this.navParams.data.id;
    });
  });
```

I would like to be able to create a selector for that specific item and use it like so:

```
this.store.select(selectors.selectItemById(this.navParams.data.id))
  .filter(data => data !== null)
  .subscribe(selectedItem => {
    this.item = selectedItem;
  });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello ! Could you share your reducer too ? I am trying to figure out what the state looks like

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After some research I solved my own problem. I used factory function to get desired `selectItemById` selector. Here is my new selector:

```
import { AppState, Item } from '../../shared/models/index';
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

export const selectItems = (state: AppState) => state.eventsState.items;

export const getItemById = (id) => createSelector(selectItems, (allItems) => {
  if (allItems) {
    return allItems.find(item => {
      return item.itemId === id;
    });
  } else {
    return {};
  }
});
```

Then all I have to do in my controller is to call this selector and pass it an id of desired item to get the item out of the store:

```
import * as selectors from '../../app/store/selectors';

this.store.select(selectors.getItemById(id))
  .subscribe((item) => {
    this.item = item;
  });
```

Comment: If you'd store entities as id based hash table your access would be O(1) instead and you wouldn't have to loop at all avoiding O(n).

Comment: This was very helpful. I wonder if there is a way to do a chaining of selectors for these factory ones too. Just like how we create sub selectors from existing ones using the createSelector method. I wonder if there is a way to do that for factories too.

Comment: How can I trigger a new select to the store if the id changes?

Comment: As of NgRx 6.0  see: https://blog.angularindepth.com/ngrx-parameterized-selector-e3f610529f8

Comment: This is way too complicated for what it does. Thanks Redux.

Comment: Hello, could you share the reducer of the store ? because I don't know what "state.eventsState.items" corresponds to

Answer (score 11):

Everything becomes much easier when using entities. 
When you store them as an object, where key is an `id` of item and value is the item itself. There are two ways for keeping items as an array - store only ids or full objects of Item.

in reducer:

```
export interface ItemsState {
  loaded: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
  items: { [key: string]: Item };
  itemIds: any[];
}

const initialState: ItemsState = {
  loaded: true,
  loading: false,
  items: {
    0: {
      foo: 'bar'
    },
    1: {
      bar: 'foo'
    }
  },
  itemIds: [0, 1]
}
```

in selectors:

```
export const getItems = (state: ItemsState) => state.items;

export const getItemById = (id) => createSelector(
  getItems, 
  (items) => items[id]
);
```

in container(component):

```
constructor(
  private store: Store,
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {}

getItemOnInit(): void {
  // or any other way to retrieve id from route
  const id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
  this.store.pipe(select(getItemById(id)));
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing a comma in your getItemById selector after getItems

Answer (score 3):

**Based on the data available in the store:**

```
export const selectUser = (state: AppState) => state.selectedUser;
export const selectAllBooks = (state: AppState) => state.allBooks;

export const selectVisibleBooks = createSelector(
  selectUser,
  selectAllBooks,
  (selectedUser: User, allBooks: Books[]) => {
    if (selectedUser && allBooks) {
      return allBooks.filter((book: Book) => book.userId === selectedUser.id);
    } else {
          return allBooks;
    }
   }
);
```

**Data that isn't available in the store:**

To select a piece of state based on data that isn't available in the store you can pass **props** to the selector function. These props gets passed through every selector and the projector function. To do so we must specify these props when we use the selector inside our component.

For example if we have a counter and we want to multiply its value, we can add the multiply factor as a prop:

The last argument of a selector or a projector is the props argument, for our example it looks as follows:

```
export const getCount = createSelector(
  getCounterValue,
  (counter, props) => counter * props.multiply
);
```

Inside the component we can define the props:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.counter = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getCount, { multiply: 2 }))
}
```

Hers is the [Documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors).